# Android 11+ Wireless Debugging not available when using Mobile Hotspot as the network

Tags: android, android-studio, android-11, adbwireless, android-12l

Before android 11, i was able to wirelessly debug apps using this method

1. turn on the mobile hotspot in the (target) android phone
2. connect the computer to the hotspot
3. run adb tcpip 5555
4. adb connect [ip of the target phone]

**The problem is**
Android 11 introduced Wireless Debugging and the above method doesn't work as expected.
And the wireless debugging mode cannot be turned on unless my android phone is connected to wifi
so it is not working because I want to use the target phone's hotspot for wireless debugging.

is there any possible solution?
or
is it possible to turn the wireless debugging mode ON even if the phone is not connected to **wifi**?

Comment: Facing the same issue, dropping le dot here for a solution

Answer (score 3):

**Work Around**

1. run `adb tcpip 5555`
2. run `adb connect [ip]`
3. go to **Settings/Display & brightness/Auto screen off** and make it **30 minutes**. (means that your phone won't auto lock so it will stay wirelessly connected to ADB)

*I hope android engineers will allow using the wireless debug feature without being connected to WiFi in newer versions of android though, as pointed to in the question.*

Comment: In addition to this answer which does work: After connecting to your wifi hotspot, type ipconfig from the computer, presumably the vscode terminal window. The IP address in the 'default gateway' section is what you will use when you type ADB CONNECT [IP]

Comment: Just to add to @MarkBowler's comment, if you're using Mac, when you connect to the hotspot, click on the Wifi icon in the menu bar, then Click on "Wifi Settings" then click on "Details" button, the router ip address seems to be almost static and does not always change if you toggle your Mobile Data Connection.  then use it like adb connect [ip]